# Как побитово проверить равенство чисел?

Tags: машинный-код

К примеру 1+1 = 2 будет в дополнительном коде 00000001 + 00000001 = 00000010, но 00000010 число 2, а не true(1) или false(0), как побитово работает условный оператор if? Я не могу понять как/чем АЛУ должно проверить что если 00000010 = 00000010 => сделать что-то

Comment: Так и проверяется - сравниваются биты. А какое отношение имеет 2 к true и false? Ps. К вопросу не относится, но как правило все, что не 0, не пустая строка, не NaN, не ещё что-нибудь принимается за true.

Answer (score 0):

На машинном уровне сравнение двух чисел выполняется через обычное арифметическое вычитание, т.е. `a == b`, если `a - b == 0`.

На примере архитектуры x86 - операция `CMP` (сравнение) - это тот же `SUB` (вычитание), за исключением того, что `CMP` никуда не сохраняет результат операции, а только изменяет [регистр флагов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80_%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2) (в частности, флаги `ZF` и `SF`). После `CMP` уже идут операции, которые учитывают значение в регистре флагов (например, операции условного перехода `JZ`/`JNZ` ("jump if zero", "jump if not zero" - переход если `ZF == 1` или наоборот если `ZF == 0`).